# Смещение рамки календаря с помощью DateTime

Tags: c#

Календарь работает. Но, не сходится нужная строка с датой. Не могу найти в чем проблема. На картинке видно проблему.[image: Снимок экрана]

```
void DrowMiniCalendar(DateTime selectedDate)
    {
        int posX = 43, posY = 19;
        string[,] days = new string[6, 7];
        int week = 0;
        int dayOfWeek = (int)FirstDayOfMonth(selectedDate).DayOfWeek - 1;
        if (dayOfWeek == -1) dayOfWeek = 6;
        int daysInMonth = LastDayOfMonth(selectedDate).Day;
        for (int day = 1; day <= daysInMonth; ++day)
        {
            days[week, dayOfWeek] = $"{day,2}";
            ++dayOfWeek;
            if (dayOfWeek == 7)
            {
                ++week;
                dayOfWeek = 0;
            }
        }
        for (int row = 0; row < 6; ++row)
        {
            for (int column = 0; column < 7; ++column)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(posX + column * 4, posY + row * 2);
                Console.Write(days[row, column] ?? "    ");
            }
        }
        DrowCurrentDayMiniCalendar(selectedDate);
    }
void DrowCurrentDayMiniCalendar(DateTime selectedDate)
    {

        int posX = 42, posY = 18;
        int column = (int)selectedDate.DayOfWeek - 1;
        if (column == -1) column = 6;

        int row = (selectedDate.Day + (int)FirstDayOfMonth(selectedDate).DayOfWeek - 2) / 7;

        Console.SetCursorPosition(posX + column * 4, posY + row * 2);
        Console.Write("┌──┐");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(posX + column * 4, posY + 1 + row * 2);
        Console.Write("│");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(posX + 3 + column * 4, posY + 1 + row * 2);
        Console.Write("│");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(posX + column * 4, posY + 2 + row * 2);
        Console.Write("└──┘");
    }
```

Comment: мне не понятна ваша проблема, поясните

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что в рассчете строки для курсора вы переводите день недели из enum в int напрямую

```
(int)FirstDayOfMonth(selectedDate).DayOfWeek
```

А в C# используется неделя в формате даты США, когда она начинается с Воскресенья

```
0 - Воскресенье
1 - Понедельник
2 - Вторник 
...
```

И если в рассчете столбца вы это учитываете

```
if (dayOfWeek == -1) dayOfWeek = 6;
```

То в рассчете строки - нет

```
int row = (selectedDate.Day + (int)FirstDayOfMonth(selectedDate).DayOfWeek - 2) / 7;
```

Замените рассчет `row` в `DrowCurrentDayMiniCalendar` на

```
int firstDayOfWeek = FirstDayOfMonth(selectedDate).DayOfWeek - 1;
if (firstDayOfWeek == -1) firstDayOfWeek = 6;

int row = (selectedDate.Day + firstDayOfWeek - 1) / 7
```

Comment: Спастбо, действительно не заметил этого момента.